Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on Thinkpad x1 Dummy output sound problem
My sound drivers used to work just fine on Ubuntu running on Thinkpad x1 10th gen but after some updates, I am only able to select Dummy Output in Output Device settings. How do I fix this? Tried several methods online, none seemed to work.

Please edit the question and add exactly what you tried and the results.
